# Is there a way to have Nest use the ExceptionsHandler error message as the API response message when an exception is thrown?

Tags: exception, error-handling, nestjs, nestjs-exception-filters

When an error is thrown within my Nest API, often times the error that is thrown is not an HttpException, and therefore the standard Nest API response that I see from the client's side is:

```
{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

But when I look at the console log, there is a much more descriptive error message, for example:

```
[Nest] 18476  - 06/23/2022, 2:28:07 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot perform update query 
because update values are not defined.
UpdateValuesMissingError: Cannot perform update query because update values are not defined.
```

Is there a way I can route this message to be the in the response body of the response given back to the API client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Global Filter](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#exception-filters-1) in NestJs to catch error and then throw a good error.

For exemple, you can create a Exception Filter

```js
// UpdateValuesMissingError.exception-filter.ts
import { ArgumentsHost, Catch, ExceptionFilter } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

@Catch(UpdateValuesMissingError)
export class UpdateValuesMissingErrorFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: UpdateValuesMissingError, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();

    console.log(exception);

    response.status(400).json({
      statusCode: 400,
      timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
      path: request.url,
    });
  }
}
```

and in your main.ts add this

`app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter());`

And now in response.status(400).json({}) you can add everything you want in your body. Like the error message of Axios.

Comment: Would I need to add a global exception filter FOR EVERY different type of error that could possibly be thrown? Or is there a way to write a global exception filter which catches all non-httpException errors?